Windows 11: Getting ConEmu to *not* create a duplicate window on each virtual desktop?
SLIGHT CORRECTION: The current available ConEmu version at my job is actually 220418 instead of what I incorrectly wrote here originally. However, the ConEmu windows still get duplicated on each virtual desktop, just as I reported below.
We're using Windows 11 at work, and the environment there is locked down without our being able to install software.
As part of my normal work, I make use of several virtual desktops in my Windows 11 environment, as this makes it easier for me to separate different aspects of the tasks that I am working on.
I very much like ConEmu, and the version available to us at work is 150504 220418. We local users are unable to download or install any other version.
However, it turns out that whenever I start a ConEmu session, the window appears on all of my virtual desktops. I do not want this. I want one and only one ConEmu terminal to appear, and only on the virtual desktop upon which I launched that particular ConEmu session. This way, I can start multiple ConEmu sessions with each of them present on whatever virtual desktop that I desire.
I could not find any way to control this one-window-only behavior in any of ConEmu's settings, but I'm hoping that I have overlooked something.
Can anyone suggest a way to force ConEmu 150504 220418 to not duplicate its terminal sessions on all Windows 11 virtual desktops?

Just checked, and the version 220418 does not appear on all virtual desktops, only on the active one.
Try to close all ConEmu instances, and run from Win+R using fresh config, ConEmu64.exe -basic.

Aha! The key is running ConEmu64 with the "-basic" flag. Without "-basic", the terminal appears on all desktops; with "-basic", the terminal only appears on the desktop from which it was launched.  Thank you!

Oh ... this doesn't quite solve my problem, after all. With "-basic", I am unable to change any of the ConEmu64 settings. I need to still find a different option that tells ConEmu64 not to open up on all virtual desktops.

I've never had ConEmu duplicated across all virtual desktops and do know -basic is not required - this is the config I use

Thank you very much! I'll try this at work when I'm back there on Monday. Then, I'll report my findings.

I ended up having to go back to work, and I tried your ConEmu64 config file there ... and it works! ... in other words, it doesn't end up opening any given session on each and every virtual desktop. So, thank you!

The solution ends up being that I just need to use the config file posted above by @JW0914:
https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/ConEmu/ConEmu.xml
Something is amiss about the default config file that gets installed on our Windows hosts at work. Now, all works well with this other config file.
